# PHP Get Id from Url .$_GET['id'];

Tags: php, curl

How can I use the

```
.$_GET['id'];
```

After `Domain.com` Like This

```
Domain.com/.$_GET['id']; 
($curl = curl_init('https://nombre.is/stream.php?mid=.$_GET['id']');)
```

If I try to do it, it's contradictory to the page file.

```
<?php
  $curl = curl_init('https://nombre.is/stream.php?mid=.$_GET['id'];');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  $page = curl_exec($curl);
  if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
  {
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
  }
  curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Has anyone an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: `$curl = curl_init('https://nombre.is/stream.php?mid='.$_GET['id']);`

Answer (score 1):

You should use string concatenation with the dot **.** operator, like so.

```
$curl = curl_init('https://nombre.is/stream.php?mid=' . $_GET['id']);
```

Comment: How can i use this one<?php
  echo curPageURL();
?>                                         
<?php

$curl = curl_init('https://nombre.is');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);       If I wanna use the pageurl after nombre.is like this nombre.is/echo curPageURL();

Comment: @hd-flix, that should be if I understood you correctly:

`echo 'nombre.is' . $curPageURL()`

Comment: hi, i have this code <?php
$curl = curl_init('https://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=deadpool&s=tt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
 echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
 exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<div class="findSection">(.*?)<div id="sidebar">/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0];
else 
    print "Not found"; 
?>               How can i get the img without the m.media-amazon.com ="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5.png

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming you want to use id value from $_GET into string URL ?

```
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $curl = curl_init("https://nombre.is/stream.php?mid=$id");
```

OR

```
  $curl = curl_init("https://nombre.is/stream.php?mid=" . $_GET['id']);
```

both will work

an other example as per your comment

```
$page_url = curPageURL();
$curl = curl_init('nombre.is/' . $page_url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$page = curl_exec($curl);
```

or

```
$curl = curl_init('nombre.is/' . curPageURL()); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$page = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: How can i use this one<?php echo curPageURL(); ?> <?php $curl = curl_init('nombre.is'); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); $page = curl_exec($curl); If I wanna use the pageurl after nombre.is like this nombre.is/echo curPageURL();

Comment: @hdflix see the answer above i have modified it and added more examples

Comment: hi, i have this code <?php
$curl = curl_init('https://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=deadpool&s=tt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
 echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
 exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<div class="findSection">(.*?)<div id="sidebar">/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0];
else 
    print "Not found"; 
?>

Comment: hi, i have this code <?php
$curl = curl_init('https://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=deadpool&s=tt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
 echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
 exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<div class="findSection">(.*?)<div id="sidebar">/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0];
else 
    print "Not found"; 
?>               How can i get the img without the m.media-amazon.com ="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5.png

Comment: too many questions, i have answered all of them none of them marked accepted by you, please mark as accepted the previous questions first.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways of doing this! You can either use `{ }` around the `$_GET` variable, which you should use when trying to pull a value from an array into a string, or you can use the concatenation operator `.` to join the two values together and append the `$_GET['id']` to the end of the URL string.

Option 1:

```
$curl = curl_init("https://nombre.is/stream.php?mid=${_GET['id']});
```

Or using the `.` operator:

```
$curl = curl_init("https://nombre.is/stream.php?mid=" . $_GET['id']);
```

Comment: How can i use this one<?php
  echo curPageURL();
?>                                         
<?php

$curl = curl_init('https://nombre.is');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);       If I wanna use the pageurl after nombre.is like this nombre.is/echo curPageURL();

Comment: @hdflix see my answer above i have modified it and added more examples

Comment: hi, i have this code <?php
$curl = curl_init('https://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=deadpool&s=tt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
 echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
 exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<div class="findSection">(.*?)<div id="sidebar">/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0];
else 
    print "Not found"; 
?>               How can i get the img without the m.media-amazon.com ="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5.png